# How can I use a weight matrix created by a trained neural network to make predictions in another file?

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I have trained a neural network classifier using keras, and it is currently predicting with 90% accuracy. I would like to make predictions on another file without having to include the entire model. Is it possible to make the predictions using just the output weight matrix? I.e, mathematically, how can I make the same classification using the weight matrix without having to re-train the model every time i get a new data input for which I need a classification prediction?

Comment: This is called "prediction" or "inference", and is covered in the documentation for your framework.

Answer (score 0):

Save your model or the weights of your model:

```
model.save(filename)
np.save(filename, model.get_weights())
```

For loading, in the first case:

```
from keras.models import load_model
model = load_model(filename)
```

In the second case:

```
#recreate the model then:
model.set_weights(np.load(filename))
```

Then:

```
results = model.predict(batch_of_data)
```